# Attendance in time and out time are on different days in [sql]

Tags: sql, time-and-attendance

I'm a newbie in [SQL] Server; I have trouble to write a sql-query to create a table for [time-and-attendance]

i am getting perfect output on in_time and out_time are on same day , but not getting in time and out time are on different time

i Have a table named  with all employee punch data with below details

| Employee_Id | Attend_date | ETime | Punch_mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 452 | 2023-03-03 00:00:00.000 | 4.52 | 2 |
| 452 | 2023-03-03 00:00:00.000 | 16.52 | 1 |
| 452 | 2023-03-03 00:00:00.000 | 16.55 | 1 |
| 452 | 2023-03-04 00:00:00.000 | 16.49 | 1 |
| 452 | 2023-03-04 00:00:00.000 | 4.51 | 2 |
| 452 | 2023-03-05 00:00:00.000 | 4.25 | 2 |

mode 2 is check out and mode 1 is check in

by using below #sql query

```
'SELECT 
 A.E_ID,
 MAX(A.Attend_date) as attendance_date,
 MIN(A.E_TIME) as IN_TIME,
 MAX(A.E_TIME) as OUT_TIME
 FROM ATT AS A
 WHERE  A.E_ID ='452' and A.Attend_date ='2023-03-03 00:00:00.000'
 group by A.attend_date'
```

i am getting this which is not correct

| E_ID | attendate | IN_TIME | OUT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 452 | 2023-03-03 00:00:00.000 | 4.52 | 16.55 |

i would like to get the data in this for above employee in below format

| empl_mach_id | attend_date | In_time | out_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 452 | 2023-03-03 00:00:00.000 | 16.52 | 4.51 |
| 452 | 2023-03-04 00:00:00.000 | 16.49 | 4.25 |

Please help me to sort out this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably post your query then.

Comment: The query includes `and A.Attend_date ='2023-03-03 00:00:00.000'`, so it is only going to return rows with that value.

Comment: And I guess the group by column name is a typo?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i have taken only one employee for particular date only for understanding . Group by column name in a typo eroor , apologies

Comment: @Rabees Please note that the query restricts it on employee ID, as you intended, but it *also* restricts it to only one date. I thought that you did *not* want it restricted to one date.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ok, i understood your concern. I am newbie in sql and it would be very appreciated if you could provide the solution .

Comment: @Rabees Delete the `and A.Attend_date ='2023-03-03 00:00:00.000'` part.